# Link menu active on 2 pages

Tags: 7, navigation, routes

I have a menu like this:

[image]

The sidebar on the left is the `Main Menu` with links. The first link is `STOCKLIJST`, that will link to the page `stocklijst/aangeboden`. As you can see in the second sidebar (this is a menu in a block that will only be visible when page starts with `stocklijst/*`) the link is active.

But when I click on the second link in the second sidebar the `'STOCKLIJST'` in the first sidebar won't be selected anymore.

Why? : Because this is a link to the first link in the second sidebar ... .

How should I could make sure that the first link is active on multiple pages? Or is the easiest way to for this with JavaScript or PHP?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the menu position and added a trigger like this:
[image]

But that doesn't do much. Something I do wrong?

Comment: Is it Drupal application?

Comment: Yes ... It's a Drupal 7 app

Comment: I used Menu Position module for active menu in my project and works great for me. Check my answer

Comment: Having a little problem to configure the Menu Position Module, could you take a look at my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by one of the  following modules

1)[Menu Position](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position)

> Often times site builders want certain types of content to appear in a specific position in the navigational menu. The simplest solution, adding all of that content individually to the menu system, has performance and usability issues. (Imagine hundreds of menu items added to one spot in the menu.)
>
> This module allows for the creation of rules that will dynamically add the current page into the menu system at the requested spots.

2) [Menu Trail By Path](https://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path)

> Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to the current url.
>
> For example if you are at yoursite.com/blog/category1/article1
>   Menu Items with these paths will get the active-trail class on them and expand accordingly.
>
> blog
>
> blog/category1
>
> blog/category1/article1